# How to select a drop-down menu item with jQuery, in a WordPress image gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

First, see screenshot to see what I'm trying to select:

[image]

In WordPress, when I click New Post, then the Add Media button, on the popup image gallery there's the image filtering drop-down menu; I want to automatically select. the "Unattached" item when that popup loads.

I'm having trouble getting this to happen. So far, in my theme's `functions.php` I have a call to the .js file with the jQuery code in it.

```
function my_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-custom', THEMATER_URL . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_scripts');
```

Then in the .js file I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#media-attachment-filters').prop('selectedIndex', 6); // select 5th option
});
```

But nothing happens. What am I missing?

**Update:**

Based on Christian Nguyen's code, I did get it to *select* the item I wanted, however, it's not actually sorting the image gallery based on that selection, so it's functionally just 'highlighting' the item. My guess is it's not triggering some `OnClick`/`OnSelect` event. I tried adding `.trigger('change')`, but still no joy. Does anyone also know how to get it to actually do so?

So far, I have this code, note that ALL of the commented out items WILL select the item, just no actual "selection" triggered to do the sorting.

```
/* When Insert Media button gets clicked ... */
$("#insert-media-button").on('click', function() {

     // Set a 'delay' of 0, & then call the function that selects the menu item.
     // NOTE: Skipping the setTimeout, & just directly call the selector doesn't work.
    setTimeout(function() {

        /* BUG: All 4 of the following WILL select the "Unattached" drop-down item,
                        However, ALL pics still get loaded, instead of JUST the UNATTACHED
                        pics, which is what we want.
        */
        //$('#media-attachment-filters').attr('selected', 'selected').trigger('change');
        //$('#media-attachment-filters').val('unattached');
        //$('#media-attachment-filters').prop('selectedIndex', 5);
        //$('#media-attachment-filters>option:eq(5)').prop('selected', true);
    }, 0);
});
```

Another thing of NOTE: in my case, the .js also wasn't being called at all in the admin area because I mistakenly only *enqueued* it for the front-end, I had to use `admin_enqueue_scripts` to get the .js to load in the admin area (back end) where the action is actually happening.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, looks like I've got it figured out; it needed `.change()` appended to the end, and I've also increased the `setTimeout()` from `0` to `10`. Depending on how fast/slow your own server is, you may want to play around with increasing/decreasing that value. Essentially it's meant to give the initial image loading a bit of time to 'load' before calling the jQuery.

Here's my final working code. Thanks again to Christian Nguyen for 99% of the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

/*  When the image gallery loads after clicking New Post | Insert Image, auto-select
 *  the "Unattached" menu item from the drop-down menu.
 */

/* When Insert Media button gets clicked ... */
$("#insert-media-button").on('click', function() {

     // Set a 'delay' of 10, & then call the function that selects the menu item.
     // NOTE: Skipping the setTimeout, & just directly call the selector doesn't work.
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#media-attachment-filters').val('unattached').change();
true);
    }, 10);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function if you have an associated `value` on your `<option>` elements. An example may include...

```
<button id="insert-media-button">Insert</button>

<select id="media-attachment-filters">
    <option value="1">All media items</option>
    <option value="2">Uploaded to this post</option>
    <option value="3">Images</option>
    <option value="4">Audio</option>
    <option value="5">Video</option>
    <option value="6">Unattached</option>
</select>
```

---

```
$(function() {
    $('#insert-media-button').on('click', function() {
        $('#media-attachment-filters').val(6); // selects Unattached
    });
});
```

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/au29r4er/)

Answer (score 1):

I have a temporary solution:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#insert-media-button").on('click', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#media-attachment-filters').val('unattached');
        }, 0);
    });
});
```

Comment: This works excellent for selecting the Unattached item; however, it's still displaying "All" items?

Answer (score 0):

In this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76125/change-the-default-view-of-media-library-in-3-5/76213) you can find 2 solutions to do what you want and a tip to remove the list options that you doesn't want.

The firsts works on `admin_footer-post-new.php` and `admin_footer-post.php` hook action and trigger the change event to the right options inside jquery `ajaxStop()` function on `$('#wpcontent')`. This solutions load all the images, so the first time is slow than the other.

The seconds on `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook action, the same jquery event but use `wp.media.view.MediaFrame.Post` to prevent to load all the image.
This solutions is faster but have some that it's easy to workaround.